# Why does Spring Security return an empty response body?

Tags: java, rest, spring-security

I have the following Spring Security config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/authenticate")
    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
    .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

I did a filter that extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to do my authentication endpoint. There are 2 methods to deal with responses of this endpoint: one if authentication is successful, another if authentication fails:

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    UserDto user = ((UserDto) authentication.getPrincipal());

    //Here is converted the roles/authorities from the user.
    List<String> roles = user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    byte[] signingKey = Constants.JWT_SECRET.getBytes();

    //Token builder.
    String token = Jwts.builder().signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKey), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
            .setHeaderParam("typ", Constants.TOKEN_TYPE)
            .setIssuer(Constants.TOKEN_ISSUER)
            .setAudience(Constants.TOKEN_AUDIENCE)
            .setSubject(user.getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 864000000))
            .claim("rol", roles)
            .compact();

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.sendError(response.getStatus(), "Bearer " + token);
}

@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("MESSAGE UNAUTHORIZED : " + failed.getMessage());

    response.sendError(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, failed.getMessage());
}
```

I use the **authenticated()** method to protect(filter) the routes. But the same, only in the filter endpoint (/user/authenticate), returns the status and a blank response body.
When I dont use this, the reponse generated by **sendError()** returns normally.

Comment: So when you successfully authenticate, the sendError() sends back an empty body?

Comment: Successfully or not. But I tried the suggestion in the answers below and it works as well. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

So actually I think that what you want is the getWriter method since sendError is not used for successfull result.

Try the following:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK); // You can use another constant if u like
response.getWritter().print("Bearer " + token);
```

Comment: Thx dude! That served as well.